# How to use ternary operators for 2 parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I want to make some clean code using ternary operators in React.js

Here is my current code:

```
if(done){
  if(res.length > 0) {
    //code here
  }else{
    //code here
  }
  //do nothing
}
```

How can I do conditional using ternary with the same logic as my code above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your code doing, though? Ternaries are great for value assignment, but if your code's more complicated than that, you should stick to the if statements.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
done && res.length>0 ? <true_case> : <false_case>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for the OP's usage; if `done` is `false`; this will evaluate the false case, but the OP's original doesn't specify what to do if `!done`.

Comment: True! @Hera then it's actually better to stick with if else as its more readable specially when dealing with nested conditions.